# Neo4j filtering nodes with only one type of relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new with neo4j and I'm stuck in this exercise. I have to find the names and cities of the students who only have friends in their city. The graph is something like this:
[image]

The name of the relationship is "FRIEND_OF", and the color represents the city.

Thanks so much.

Comment: is the city stored as a property on the user node?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Yeah, all user nodes have Name and City, for example to create one:
create(:User{Name:'Juan', City:'Madrid'});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the city property is stored on the node, you can add a WHERE clause :

```
MATCH (user:User)
MATCH (user)-[:FRIEND_OF]-(friend)
WHERE user.city = friend.city
RETURN user.name, collect(distinct(friend)) as friends
```

**EDIT**
If you want to return users where all his friends lives in the same city, try this one :

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:FRIEND_OF]->(friend)
WITH user, collect(friend) AS friends
WHERE ALL (x IN friends 
           WHERE x.city = user.city)
RETURN user
```

Comment: Thx but this is not the correct answer... It must return the users that ONLY have friends in their citys, and this return the user that have friends in their citys, but if they have in other city its returned too :( I have wrote the same query before.

Comment: as you can see, it returns a collection of friends that are in the same city of the user

Comment: Yes, but it returns the users that have friends in other citys too. If A have two friends, B (from the same city) and C (from other city), It will return A, and It shouldn't. In SQL I think it should be with a "not in [users that have friends in other citys]" to filter, but in neo4j I don't know how to do it.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much! :) now I know how to do it hehe